# Azure PHP8 exposing php code

Tags: nginx, php, azure

My website runs fine BUT when i add ".PHP" in uppercase to my URL e.g. [www.example.com/test.PHP](http://www.example.com/test.PHP) my php code is exposed on the website source code.

I'm running PHP8 on azure.

My NGIX config are as follows:

```
server {
#proxy_cache cache;
#proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
listen 8080;
listen [::]:8080;
root /home/site/wwwroot;
index  index.php;
server_name  example.net www.example.net; 
port_in_redirect off;

default_type text/html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @ext;
}

location ~ \/\.php {
    rewrite "^(.*)\/.php" $1.php last;
}

location @ext {
    rewrite "^(.*)$" $1.php;
}

location ~ \/\.php {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

error_page 403 404  /error.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
    fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
    fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
}
```

Can't think for the life of me on how to resolve this issue.

**UPDATE**:

added below which now redirects it to an error page

```
  location ~ \.PHP$ {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }
```

Comment: It looks like this is caused by the nginx configuration being case sensitive; file endings in ".PHP" are not recognized as PHP files and are thus not handled by the PHP interpreter.

Comment: is there a way to disable this or rewrite it to lower case? or redirect to an error page if .PHP is entered

Comment: I added :
    `code`
    location ~ \.PHP$ {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
     } `code`

and got it to redirect to an error page instead